# Cloudkit query array size == 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

I'm performing query operation with Cloudkit, my record type is like this:

```
CKRecord Type: Person
{
  name STRING,
  age  INTEGER,
  friends  ARRAY,
}
```

Now, I want to query all person with no friends.I have tried

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [[NSPredicate alloc] initWithFormat: @"friends[SIZE] == 0"];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithPredicate: predicate];
```

And

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [[NSPredicate alloc] initWithFormat: @"friends.@count == 0"];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithPredicate: predicate];
```

The first one crashed with warning

> friends[SIZE] is not an evaluated object expression

and second one returning error of

> Invalid predicate

So , what is the correct way to query with array size?

Comment: I don't see "count" or "size" in the list: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery?language=objc So I'm wondering if that's possible.

Comment: @Larme I found format 'array[SIZE]' in NSPredicate Programming Guide, but it won't work

Comment: From the doc: `The CKQuery class supports only a subset of the predicate behaviors offered by the full NSPredicate class.`, so that's maybe the case.

Comment: @Larme Thank you Larme, Now I have to add another field to track the array count, though ugly but works.

Comment: Apple highly recommends NOT using an array to store relationship data - it should be done with actual reference fields.  Look at the 2016 WWDC video "CloudKit Best Practices" - starting around 33:30 they start talk a bit about why not to use an array to reference other records.  Here's the link to the video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/231